# How to lock a raw of database until another action

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to make a crud form that there are two admins also use it. When the admin want to edit, they click on a button 1 to show a modal that contain crud form. After editing they click on button 2 to confirm the changes. Desiring is that while admin 1 is editing a raw of database, admin 2 will not able to see or update that raw. Locking time is from button is clicked to button 2 is click.
I found two solutions but still not able to solve my problem.

1. Using something like this:

```
   try{
   DB::beginTransaction();
   //Do some stuff on DB here ...
   // In Laravel i see below to prevent modifying or selecting.
   //DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->lockForUpdate()->get();

   // after update
   DB::commit();
   }
   catch(Exception $e){
   DB::rollback();
   }
```

But i don't know how to use it in my purpose.

2. Add one more locking status (0 is not clocked, 1 is clocked) column to manage. If button 1 is clicked, the status is changed to 1, and if button 2 is clicked, status is changed to 0. But how about admin close browser before clicking button 2 or electric interrupt when editing.

Comment: What you mean by "while admin 1 is editing a raw of database, admin 2 will not able to see or update that raw", you mean editing it directly in PHPMyadmin for instance?

Comment: not editing directly in PHPMyadmin. Edit in view.

Comment: I think it won't be wise to use transaction for locking something across multiple requests. It would be better to save a variable in the database or filesystem, which you should check before loading the form. Alternatively you could consider using the [Symfony lock component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html)

Comment: @PtrTon Thank your for your advice